To what does ibrav correspond?
Compound has cif which is cubic in structure. Upon converting it to scf using input generator, it turns to primtive cell. When it is vc-relaxed it remains cubic with a bit distortion.However, when it is turned into conventional cell format, it is monoclinic structurally.
Now, to get bandstructure, we require K path, but it requires particular path, which in turn depends upon ibrav. According to which format (conventional or primitive) should i set ibrav?
Is it possible that we have one structure in primitive cell and other structure in conventional cell?

The answer will be based on my basic understanding.

At first, the physical results such as band structure or DOS or however should NOT change if you use conventional or primitive, but the visualization WILL change. So, lattice parameters will change as a consequence. while lattice parameters are different, but they can be transformed into the conventional lattice from primitive and vice versa, follow this:
https://dannyvanpoucke.be/vasp-tutor-creating-a-unit-cell-from-a-super-cell-en/

So, the same system can be expressed by primitive and conventional and they will differ only in the visualization because the primitive cell is the smallest repeating unit of the crystal lattice (minimum number of atoms to describe periodicity), while the conventional cell is larger because it represents the symmetry elements that form the whole structure to be cubic, tetragonal or monoclinic and so on and therefore the whole structure becomes with the real visualization.
Usually, I think that ibrav can be 0 if you use a primitive cell in general. it can be 1 for both primitive and conventional of  simple cubic because the simple cubic lattice is a primitive by its definition (contains ONLY 1 point).


if your conventional turned after relaxation into a monoclinic structure that means a lot of changes happened and the symmetry is reduced, while you can't assess what is the symmetry of primitive easily. The real representation is conventional. so you need to find a way to transform your primitive into conventional and then see if there is any deviation. If you know that this primitive structure is 1/8 of the conventional so make a superstructure that contains an additional unit cell in x and both unit cells repeated in y and z as an example.
why using primitive cells is preferred while it is hard to be visualized? because a smaller number of atoms means faster and more efficient calculations.
Setting ibrav I prefer to be consistent during calculations, if you start with conventional complete with it, if start with primitive complete with primitive for all calculations.
as an example if you looked at this link:
https://legacy.materialsproject.org/materials/mp-126/#
you can download the symmetrized conventional and primitive.
The conventional is fcc with lattice parameters of 3.97677000 angstrom and angle is 90 degree (because it is a cubic one), while primitive has 2.81200103 A for lattice parameters and 60 degree for angles.
That means the cubic shape of conventional is a trigonal one in the primitive. The relationship between the cell parameters: 3.97677 angstrom (conventional) approximately = 2.81200 Å (primitive) * sqrt (2) . By looking to the volume you will find 4 primitive cells = 1 conventional cell. This means both are the same and describing the same material and therefore the same properties so can't have a structure from the conventional and another from primitive fundamentally.
In Brillouin zone, it is based on the primitive vectors to find the primitive reciprocal lattice vectors. So you choose the path of the primitive one. You van use seekpath for this.
The most important that the physical properties should be the same for both representations.
